# Respond with MMS via MVC controller (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, twilio, mms

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73736404/2569697), I listed how I'm currently using a functional MVC controller on an ASP.NET IIS site to handle some of the incoming SMS/MMS messages for my Twilio phone number. However, I've been unable to find the appropriate documentation for the next stage of what I'm wanting to accomplish:

**How do I *respond* with an MMS message?**
The full code listing for my `SMSController` is in the linked SO question and seems to work fine for sending basic text-only SMS messages, but I'm running into difficulty trying to get it to send MMS messages. I've tried constructing a `Messaging.Message` object by setting the `.Body()` and `.Media()` options:

```
[...]
If SMSMessage.ToUpper.Trim = "JEDI" Then
    Dim Response As New Messaging.Message

    Response.Body(JediCode)
    Response.Media(New Uri("https://my.domain.com/content/media/jedi.gif"))

    SMSResponse.Message(Response)
[...]
```

This method overload seems to *almost* work - *it sends the image, but the GIF's animation is somehow lost* - but, for one thing, the IDE is flagging it with a warning that that method is deprecated and to use the `.Append()` method instead. I tried that but it seems to fail to send *anything* and the Error Logs in my Twilio console show an `HTTP retrieval failure`.

Obviously, the above code is just while I play around and test things, but there is a definite possibility that we would be sending animated images as a part of the business flow of our use case. Is there something I'm missing here to *properly* send an MMS message as a response to an incoming SMS?

Comment: Both `.Message` and `.Append` should work but I'd recommend using `.Append` as `.Message` is deprecated which means it could be removed in the future. There really shouldn't be a difference tho.
Here's a minimal code snippet that responds with an MMS and the GIF is moving when received by the user: https://gist.github.com/Swimburger/90ece2870c4a751d18cdac4d8def8b49
Here's evidence of the moving GIF: https://media.giphy.com/media/k0O8et4M62iL6zauxg/giphy.gif

Comment: Can you share the resulting TwiML that you produce by logging `SMSResponse.ToString()`? The TwiML should be the same for when using `.Message` and `.Append`.

Comment: As for the GIF not moving, I am not sure if it is because of the messaging app you are viewing this in, or if the GIF has some issues, but when using that globe GIF, it seems to be moving.

Comment: Crap! Now the `Append()` method seems to be working as it should. Maybe I "tweaked" something since I posted this that fixed the problem. As for the GIF movement, it looks like you're correct there as well. When I look at it on my phone, I get no animation, but when I look at it through a browser-based view of my message app, I see the GIF exactly as it's supposed to be. Thank you for following up with me, though.

Comment: You're welcome! I'll put this in a concise answer later, but gotta run right now.
I am also working on your related question. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an MVC sample with VB.NET to send an MMS using TwiML the same way you are. When I receive the MMS the GIF does move, so it is likely that the SMS app you're using doesn't support moving GIFs.
Here's the code I used:

```vb
Imports Twilio.AspNet.Mvc
Imports Twilio.TwiML
Imports Twilio.TwiML.Messaging

Public Class HomeController
    Inherits TwilioController

    Function Index() As TwiMLResult
        Dim response As New MessagingResponse
        Dim message As New Message
        message.Body("Check out this GIF:")
        message.Media(New Uri("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif"))
        response.Append(message)

        Return TwiML(response)
    End Function
End Class
```

Here's what the MMS looks like in my SMS app:
[image: SMS app viewing GIF MMS]

---

Regarding using `.Message` vs `.Append`, they should work the same but `.Message` with that specific method signature is deprecated meaning it may be removed in the future. Ultimately, when you return the `MessagingResponse` using the `TwiML` method, or use `.ToString` on it, the resulting TwiML string should be the same.